# ASP.NET- Gridview not display image on a web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

i've been trying and trying to find a method to display images on a webpage using gridview. to fill the grid view i am using data table. it isn't giving any error and yet not displaying the image.

Here is my code.

```
            DataTable validationGraph = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dcol = new DataColumn("FilePath", typeof(Image)); 
            validationGraph.Columns.Add(dcol);
            Image img = new Image();
                img.ImageUrl = "~/ClientLogo.png";
                img.DataBind();
                DataRow drow = validationGraph.NewRow();
                drow["FilePath"] = img;
                validationGraph.Rows.Add(drow);

            ValidationsGridView.DataSource = validationGraph;
            ValidationsGridView.DataBind();
```

here is the html for that code:

```
           <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" 
      runat="server">
            </asp:Content>
            <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
            &nbsp;
            <asp:GridView ID="ValidationsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
            Font-Names = "Arial" >
            <Columns>
             <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="FilePath" ControlStyle-Width="100"
                 ControlStyle-Height = "100" HeaderText = "Preview Image"/>

             </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>
              </asp:Content>
```

My code is not showing the picture on the web page still.

Kindly help me. :(

Comment: Where your image is stored? inside images folder?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right path to image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need an Image object. As far as I remember, your datacolumn should be of type string (as it's only holding a path)

```
DataColumn dcol = new DataColumn("FilePath", typeof(string));
```

and the value of your field should just be the path:

```
drow["FilePath"] = "/ClientLogo.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding image with img tag inside item template

```
       <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img src="path" /></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

look like you want to bind img using byte type not img Path?

if you want ImageField Show img by file path

you can use like this

```
            DataTable validationGraph = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dcol = new DataColumn("FilePath", typeof(string));
            validationGraph.Columns.Add(dcol);
            DataRow drow = validationGraph.NewRow();

            drow["FilePath"] = "~/ClientLogo.png";

            validationGraph.Rows.Add(drow);
            ValidationsGridView.DataSource = validationGraph;
            ValidationsGridView.DataBind();
```

you need be ensure "~/ClientLogo.png" is right img path

hope it can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this code you are giving ***datasource*** so you can do it like this

I am assured that your datatable have data and correct path

Let say that your image is inside

### images/ClientLogo.png

folder

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" 
      runat="server">
            </asp:Content>
            <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
            &nbsp;
            <asp:GridView ID="ValidationsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
            Font-Names = "Arial" >
            <Columns>
             <asp:ImageField ImageUrl='<%#"~/images/" +(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath").ToString())%>' ControlStyle-Width="100"
                 ControlStyle-Height = "100" HeaderText = "Preview Image"/>

             </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>
              </asp:Content>
```

Comment: 'DataImageUrlField' and 'ImageUrl' in ImageFeild. Is it correct ?

Comment: you should remove the ImageUrl property in place of DataImageUrlField from the ImageField. For more details please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Backend code (.cs file):

```
    DataTable validationGraph = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dcol = new DataColumn("FilePath", typeof(Image)); 
    validationGraph.Columns.Add(dcol);
    DataRow drow = validationGraph.NewRow();
    drow["FilePath"] = "~/ClientLogo.png";;
    validationGraph.Rows.Add(drow);

    ValidationsGridView.DataSource = validationGraph;
    ValidationsGridView.DataBind();
```

Frontend code (aspx file) :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <asp:GridView ID="ValidationsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"             Font-Names = "Arial" >
      <Columns>
         <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField=<%# Eval("FilePath") %> ControlStyle-Width="100"
             ControlStyle-Height = "100" HeaderText = "Preview Image"/>

         </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```